# Matlab triangulate and plot cylindrical point cloud in 3D

Tags: matlab, 3d, plot, triangulation, delaunay

I have a question relating to plotting a cylindrical surface in Matlab. My dataset consists of a point cloud of `X, Y, Z` coordinates with corresponding intensity values `C`.

I can plot them using the `scatter3` function:

```
figure
scatter3(X,Y,Z,8,C)
```

results in the following image:

However, I would like to plot the surface of this object rather than the points. I have tried to achieve this using Delaunay triangulation

```
tri     = delaunay(X,Y);
figure
trisurf(tri,X,Y,Z,C,'FaceColor','interp')
```

[Link to screenshots](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1xh0faskno7m46e/01.jpg)

As you can see from the image the result is not what I would like as there are difficulties with the triangulation. To me it seems as if the algorithm does not cope well with the fact that I get the same `X` and `Y` coordinates multiple times.

Following the examples introduced on the `TriRep` help page I have tried to use the following approach:

```
dt = DelaunayTri(X,Y,Z);
tr = TriRep(dt, X, Y, Z);
```

alas without success as I get the following error message when calling the `TriRep` function:

??? Error using ==> TriRep
   Parameter must be 'double matrix'.

I guess I have to constrain my geometry and I thought I found the solution in [Example 1 here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/trirep.freeboundary.html) by using the `freeBoundary` function - though I do need the output of the `TriRep` function in order to calculate this. That's where I am stuck. As you can see I am no expert in triangulation methods and I would really appreciate any help you could offer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is not a simple triangulation, but rather the convex hull of your set of points.

The classic analogy for a convex hull in 2d -
If you imagine your set of points to be nails on a board, then the convex hull is the polygon that would be formed by stretching a rubber band around your points - that is, it touches the external points but not the internal ones.

And extending this, you can think of the 3d convex hull as being a "skin" of the outside points in your point cloud.

The convex hull is the starting point for more complicated Computational Geometry techniques, but in your case will give you the mesh you are looking for.

I haven't used Matlab's version, but it looks pretty straightforward:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/convhulln.html

Edit: After seeing your comments below:
If you are already using a TriRep structure, you can use it to get the face normals, then delete any triangles whose face has a normal close to straight up/down.  EG, if you start with the example from Matlab's FaceNormals doc page http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/trirep.facenormals.html :

```
numpts = 100;
thetha = rand(numpts,1)*2*pi;
phi = rand(numpts,1)*pi;
x = cos(thetha).*sin(phi);
y = sin(thetha).*sin(phi);
z = cos(phi);
dt = DelaunayTri(x,y,z);
[tri Xb] = freeBoundary(dt);
tr = TriRep(tri, Xb);
P = incenters(tr);
fn = faceNormals(tr);
trisurf(tri,Xb(:,1),Xb(:,2),Xb(:,3), 'FaceColor', 'cyan', 'faceAlpha', 0.8);
```

Then you can simply run through the normals, and remove any faces with a high z magnitude:

```
for(i=196:-1:1)
    if(abs(fn(i,3))>0.8)
        tri(i)=[];
    end
end
trisurf(tri,Xb(:,1),Xb(:,2),Xb(:,3),'FaceColor','red','faceAlpha',0.7);
```

HTH -- RC

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in this direction. I have tried it out and it looks much better though still not quite what I was after. Currently There are too few faces on the surfaces and the cylinder is also closed on the top and bottom end. What I had in mind was an open cylinder with as many small faces on the side walls as possible without overlap. Do you have an idea how I could achieve this?

Comment: Using T = delaunayn(X,{'Qt','Qc','Qx','Q4'}); I was able to get some new results that are really close to what I want (I won't use the convex hull after all as this will omit points given that the cylinder is not completely convex). My last problem now remains the fact that the top and bottom face of the cylinder is closed. Is there any way specifying a 'maximum triangulation distance' in delaunayn? If I could specify a maximum length of the triangle face then I could easily avoid filling the top and bottom faces...

Comment: Just a note: the for loop runs down instead of up so you don't have to mess with figuring out indexing after removing rows.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for your help. I think this will do the job!